# 'Sequence contains more than one element' when DBContext Find is called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using MVC for my web app. And would need help in the following scenario.

I have 3 tables in my Database:

1. Page : Contains list of pages. Primary Key: ID_PAGE
2. Role : Contains list of roles. Primary Key: ID_ROLE
3. Role_Page : Contains list of pages and its related roles. No Primary Key. Only Foreign Keys of ID_PAGE & ID_ROLE.

These tables are then mapped to their own respective model classes.

Using scaffolding, I create Controllers and Views based on the 'Role_Page' model.

Now, on clicking of 'Edit', I pass in the respective ID_ROLE and ID_PAGE as parameters to the 'Find' method of DBContext.

However I am getting 'Sequence contains more than one element' when that method is called.

Any help and pointers is highly appreciated!

---

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? ID_ROLE, int? ID_JOB)
    {
        if (ID_ROLE == null || ID_JOB == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ROLE_JOB rt_ROLE_JOB = db.ROLE_JOB.Find(ID_ROLE, ID_JOB);
        if (rt_ROLE_JOB == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(rt_ROLE_JOB);
    }
```

Comment: This says there is more than one item for that combination in DB whereas it's expecting single item. can you paste your edit action code?

Comment: @qamar Thanks. I just added my controller code. Its pretty much the same default code from scaffolding except the edited parameters for 'Find'

Comment: So basically your  db.ROLE_JOB.Find(ID_ROLE, ID_JOB); returning more than one row. You are trying to assign these rows to ROLE_JOB which is expecting a single row. So you either can do db.ROLE_JOB.Find(ID_ROLE, ID_JOB).FirstorDefault(); to get the first row or investigate why multiple row is returned whereas the combination supposed to be unique

Comment: @qamar Yep, records were indeed repeating. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Find` requires a primary key. You're trying to use it on a table that doesn't have a primary key. Is problem.

What you want is something like:

`YourContext.Role_Pages.Single(x => x.ID_PAGE == somePageID && x.ID_ROLE == someRoleID)`

Note that `Single` will throw an exception either if no record is found or if more than one record is found. You should look into other LINQ functions - `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, `Any`, `Where` etc and use as appropriate.

Comment: Hi Chris, Yep its make sense now. There is indeed repeating records. Will be using different LINQ functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Find` needs to provide the [Table] `Primary Key` you can also provide your `key` as a predicate

`DbContext.ROLE_JOB.Find(a => a.ID_ROLE== ID_ROLE);` OR `DbContext.ROLE_JOB.Find(a => a.Id == ID_ROLE && a.ID_JOB == ID_JOB);`

It will return you a single record if found successfully.